# High rigidbody drag value gives weird speed readings

Tags: unity, c#, physics, movement, rigidbody

when calculating speed in unity

```js
    public float speed = 0;

Vector3 lastPosition = Vector3.zero;

 void FixedUpdate()
 {
     speed = (transform.position - lastPosition).magnitude;
     lastPosition = transform.position;
 }
```

It all goes well... However when increasing the drag value of the objects rigidbody component to 100 this speed value goes haywire! I have made a physics based movement system using the addforce rigidbody function to move along whichever local axis and used drag as a replacement for ground friction when walking along a surface becuase physics materials didnt work

How can I get a proper speed reading?

Comment: Rigidbody(2d) has velocity property.

Comment: How would i write that? I am in a unity 3d scene... i did:
        float speedInUnitPerSecond = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.magnitude;
but im using a 3d rb not 2d... and im not sure how to calculate last position using vector 2...

Comment: Just use the 3d one - `float speedInUnitPerSecond = GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.magnitude;`